# Neo4j Transaction and Open Handles

Tags: typescript, neo4j, jestjs

I'm observing a strange beahviour with the neo4j driver and Jest.

A simple test run with `jest --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --testTimeout=10000`

```
describe("Test", () => {
  test("Test handle", async () => {
    const address = `bolt://${host}`;
    const credentials = neo4j.auth.basic(user, password);
    const driver = neo4j.driver(address, credentials, { encrypted: false });
    const session = driver.session();
    const tx = session.beginTransaction();
    await tx.commit();
    console.log({ open: tx.isOpen() });
    await session.close();
  });
});
```

Raises the error:

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

      19 |     const driver = neo4j.driver(address, credentials, { encrypted: false });
      20 |     const session = driver.session();
    > 21 |     const tx = session.beginTransaction();
         |                              ^
      22 |     await tx.commit();
      23 |     console.log({ open: tx.isOpen() });
      24 |     await session.close();
```

Which is strange. The transaction object is closed (log open: false) at the end, so I'm not supposed to have any open handle here.

But the following is even stranger:

```
describe("Test", () => {
  test("Test handle", async () => {
    const address = `bolt://${host}`;
    const credentials = neo4j.auth.basic(user, password);
    const driver = neo4j.driver(address, credentials, { encrypted: false });
    const session = await driver.session(); // driver.session typescript signature is NOT a promise, NOR any kind of async. But Hey, it works.
    const tx = session.beginTransaction();
    await tx.commit();
    console.log({ open: tx.isOpen() });
    await session.close();
  });
});
```

Works just fine. No warning of any kind.
Do you have any explanation for that behaviour ?

Thanks,